# Проблема с конкурентным доступом к файлу

Tags: python, файлы

Смотрите есть функция.

```
def main(name, count):
with open(r'Аккаунты.txt', 'r') as file:
    accounts = file.readlines()
    account = accounts[0]
    accounts.pop(0)
    with open(r'Аккаунты.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(accounts)
        print("\n" + account.rstrip(), name)
```

В неё передаются аргументы от модуля threading.
начинает выполнять функцию и берёт 1 и ту же строку, и вот нужно решить эту проблему искал в интернете по этому вопросу слишком много чего то у кого то код для этого 100 строк не понятно как пользоваться и т.д

В общем я не могу понять эту тему прошу объяснить как так реализовать..

Comment: "В неё передаются аргументы от модуля threading" что то я не увидел в вашем коде

Comment: Не модифицируйте обрабатываемую очередь в потоках. Модифицируйте всё в главном потоке, а дочерним потокам отдавайте элементы в обработку. Если опасаетесь, что что-то не обработается - ждите результата от потоков и уже по результату модифицируйте очередь обработки. (В вашем случае очередь - это файл Аккаунты.txt) Почитайте про `multiprocessing.Pool`, например, там отдача и получение данных элементарная.